Three generations of a family sit in a row
Ten persons A to J (according to alphabet series) of three
generations live in a family and they sit in a linear row for a
game but not necessarily in the same order. Some of them face
north while some face south.
Three persons sit between A’s husband and G’s husband and
both face the same direction. H is the only son of B and sits
adjacent to G’s husband. Immediate neighbours of H do not
face north. Mother of E sits immediate right of H who sits sixth
to the right of C. One person sits between C and G who is the
sibling of H and J. D’s wife is the only neighbour of G. E sits
second to the left of J’ brother and faces south. Two persons
sit between B and A. F and A sits immediate left to each other.
C is son of F. Father of E sits immediate right of B. G and D face
the same direction but opposite to J’s mother-in-law. E and G
have same gender. How are they oriented?
Source: SBI PO Mains Previous Year Paper 2021
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pCHM-EQ9o-jPwegfronBXnXH7VvwRZ36/view?usp=sharing

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

I found the question at:  https://www.bankersadda.com/wp-content/uploads/multisite/2022/12/16175829/SBI-PO-Mains-Previous-Year-Paper-2021.pdf

If that's the source, then the question violates our rule against puzzles whose creators have asked to not be shared; see their TOS, "You agree not to copy, republish, frame, download, transmit, modify, adapt, create derivative works based on, rent, lease, loan, sell, assign, distribute, display, perform, license, sublicense or reverse engineer [our stuff]"

it's a Govt. Bank exam question.

Please read the link in my first comment. Proper attribution must be more specific. E.g. a link to a specific exam sheet.

That Google drive link isn't publicly accessible

It is  publicly accessible now.

Let's number our pieces of information:

Three persons sit between A’s husband and G’s husband and both face the same direction.
H is the only son of B and sits adjacent to G’s husband.
Immediate neighbours of H do not face north.
Mother of E sits immediate right of H who sits sixth to the right of C.
One person sits between C and G who is the sibling of H and J.
D’s wife is the only neighbour of G.
E sits second to the left of J’s brother and faces south.
Two persons sit between B and A.
F and A sits immediate left to each other.
C is son of F.
Father of E sits immediate right of B.
G and D face the same direction but opposite to J’s mother-in-law.
E and G have same gender.

Some positional deductions:

 Fact 6 means G must be sat at one end (let's say the first end, we'll figure out later if that's west or east). Then fact 5 means C is third from the same end. Then fact 4 means H is ninth. Facts 4 and 2 tells us that eighth and tenth are (in some order) the mother of E and the husband of G. So far we have: G*C*****H*

Some directional deductions:

 Fact 3 means the eighth and tenth persons face south, and fact 1 means so does A's husband, who is either fourth or sixth depending on which of eighth and tenth is G's husband.

Some relational deductions:

 Fact 2 tells us that H is the only son of B, and fact 5 tells us that H has (at least) two siblings, J and the person sitting second (D's wife), who must therefore both be female. J's mother-in-law is mentioned in fact 12, so J is married, as are A, D, G from facts 1 and 6. We now have six people in the same generation (J, J's spouse, H, H's wife, D, D's wife) and at least one in the generation above.

Something fixed:

 Fact 7 tells us E sits second to the left of J's brother, which we know is H. Since H is ninth, E must be seventh, and that means H faces up (according to our left-right chart, but we still don't know if that's north or south), therefore E's mother is tenth and G's husband is eighth and A's husband is fourth. So far we have: G*C***E*H* Then, fact 8 tells us that A and B have two people between them, so they must be either second and fifth, or fifth and eighth, in some order. Fact 9 tells us A is next to F, so A cannot be second or eighth and must be fifth, meaning B is second or eighth and F is fourth or sixth. Now we have: G, D's wife (B?), C, A's husband (F?), A, (F?), E, G's husband (B?), H, E's mother

Some generational deductions:

 Assuming no incest, D's wife can't be B because H is the son of B and D's wife is H's sister. Thus, B is eighth and is G's husband. Fact 11 says B is next to the father of E, who can't be E and therefore must be H, who is the son of B. So E is in the youngest generation, and both parents of E are present (H is E's father) plus at least two grandparents (B is H's father and also G's husband). Now we have: G, D's wife, C, A's husband (F?), A, (F?), E, B, H, E's mother (unknown positions are D, F, I, J). We know D has a wife who is not A or B, so the only place for D is sixth, which means F is fourth and is A's husband. We also know J is the sister of H, who is the father of E, therefore J can't be E's mother (again assuming no incest), but also J can't be D's wife since that person is J's sibling by fact 5  ... so there's no place for J in the lineup G, D's wife, C, F, A, D, E, B, H, E's mother.

I seem to have reached a contradiction?
